# Prove that if If $[x]=[y]$ then $[x^2]=[y^2]$

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, relations, equivalence-relations

I was asked the following question. Where $[x]$ denotes the equivalence class of an integer $x$ with regards to the modular arithmetic relation.

**Question**: Prove that if $[x]=[y]$ then $[x^2]=[y^2]$ without using the fact that multiplication behaves well with respect to equivalence classes.

**My Proof**:Given that $[x]=[y]$. We see that $x\equiv y$ (mod d) as the equality implies $x\in [y]$ and $y\in [x]$. Using a property of congruences that if $a\equiv b$ (mod d) then $a^k\equiv b^k$ (mod d)  we see that $x\equiv y$ (mod d) $\implies x^2 \equiv y^2$ (mod d)

Because congruences form an equivalence relation, the above result implies that if $a\in [y^2]$ then $a\in [x^2]$ and that if $b\in [x^2]$ then $b\in [y^2]$. Thus, $[x^2]\subset [y^2]$ and $[y^2]\subset [x^2]$. Hence, $[x^2]=[y^2]$.

I was told that this is wrong as I use that multiplication of equivalence classes. Now I get why that is being said, but I never multiply an equivalence class with another as that would make the proof trivial.

**Proof** Given that $[x]=[y]$. Multiply both sides by $[x]$ to get $[x^2]=[yx]$. Again with the equality $[x]=[y]$, multiply both sides by $[y]$ to get $[yx]=[y^2]$. Thus, $[x^2]=[yx]=[y^2]$.

I never use that fact in that manner. Is my proof wrong with regards to the question?

Comment: You “never multiply an equivalence class with another”? It sure looks like you did!

Comment: @TedShifrin I can see why it looks like that but that's not what I had in mind when I wrote $x\equiv y$ (mod d) $\implies x^k\equiv y^k$ (mod d). I took the question to mean that we shouldn't multiply the equivalence class with another to prove the statement like I did in the second proof. I get that what I did in my first proof is pretty much the same as multiplying by another equivalence class but again I wasn't thinking about it like that. All being said I don't think there is any point for me to pursue this further as it won't change anything. Should have just proved it as suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If $d\mid(x-y)$ then $x-y=kd$ for some integer $k$.

So, $x=y+kd$ and $x^2=y^2+2kd+k^2d^2$.

Then $x^2-y^2=(2k+d)d$ that is $d\mid(x^2-y^2)$.

**Addendum:**

With this same technique you could prove that
if $[a]=[b]$ and $[c]=[d]$ then $[ac]=[bd]$.

This is equivalent to suppose
$a\equiv b\!\!\!\!\mod d$ and $c\equiv d\!\!\!\!\mod d$ and then imply
$ac\equiv bd\!\!\!\!\mod d$.

Comment: I appreciate you giving a hint, but I wanted to know if I was wrong in my proof about using multiplication with respect to equivalence classes.

Comment: this hint helps to prove the property of congruences you mentioned, for any $k$ you need.

Comment: Yeah I can see that it helps prove it, but the question was if my proof was wrong with regards to multiplication of equivalence classes.

Comment: It is false that $y\in[y^2]$ in general.

Comment: Yeah I accidentally used the same symbol twice. What I was trying to say was that if an element $a\in [y^2]$ then $a\in [x^2]$ and then show the inclusion in the other direction to conclude that $[x^2]=[y^2]$.

Comment: You should rewrite that paragraph better, then

Comment: Yeah I agree I should have been more clear about that. I will edit the post now and rewrite the proof again. Thanks!

Comment: The "problem" with your proof is that the question mentioned "the fact that multiplication behaves well with respect to equivalence classes" couldn't be used. Your teacher probably considered that you used this fact when you wrote "if a≡b (mod d) then ak≡bk (mod d)".

Comment: @Taladris Yeah I think so too